# WATCHOS 2 - CORE DATA - IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Estou tentando fazer uma comunicação entre o `core data e o watch 2`.

No `iphone` adiciono um registro no core data `(sqlite)`. Quando saiu do app do `iphone` e entro no `app do watch` ele tem que ir no core data e buscar os registros. Ao fazer isso está dando um erro no meu `persistentStoreCoordinator`.

Erro ocorre na linha 89 (try
coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType,
configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)

> [image: meu persistentStoreCoordinator)]
>
> **O erro que dá é : domain: unable to read data - code: 9999**

Comment: poderia editar sua pergunta, a parte do "... ![meu pensistentStore ...." está confuso. Seja bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Comment: editei lá @David .. .vlw!